# Systematic error of constant speed

Tags: error-analysis

Given a constant unknown speed $m$ and $n$ data samples of (position, time). Performing a linear regression yields $y = mx + c$, and a **statistical error** on $m$ and $c$.
I already have this values.

Under the assumption that the systematic errors for the timer and length measurement device are $\pm 1s$ resp. $\pm 0.05 m$. What is the **systematic error** of the speed $m$

I know that $m(x, y) = \frac{y - c}{x}$.

Normally I'd use following approach for propagation of error: $\Delta m = \left\lvert \frac{\partial m}{\partial y} \right\rvert \Delta y + \left\lvert \frac{\partial m}{\partial x} \right\rvert \Delta x$.
But I don't have 1 fix pair $(x,y)$, I have *n* samples, so this approach seems wrong to me.

Comment: You say "systematic errors", but don't you mean random errors? You're not claiming that all of the data points have the same systematic error offset in either time or position, right? Also, I don't think that it is possible to determine the error in the speed m unless you provide the actual (x,y) data points. For example, if you have just two (x,y) data points, then the error in m would of course depend on how far apart the two data points are. If they are closely spaced, then that would correspond to a large error in m, and if they are widely spaced then you would have a small error in m.

Comment: you need all data points because you need to compute minimum squares

Comment: I have all data points, and I already have the random/statistical error based on least squares (a plotting tool already did that). I should have mentioned that in the question. I want the statistical error based on the precision of the used devices.

Comment: *I want the systematic error based on the precision of the used devices

Comment: Still a bit confused by the question. Why are you interested in the error in the slope m due to a systematic error in x or y? If you know that all your x's or y's have some constant systematic error then you can simply subtract out that systematic error from all your x's or y's. In my own experience, when we speak of "systematic errors" we mean that there is some effect that biases the data points but we're unable to really quantify the effect. If we could quantify the effect, then we would probably be able to subtract out the error and there would be no systematic error.

Comment: Systematic error, as I learned it, are errors/limited accuracy in used devices. If I have +- 1 second accuracy on taking the time with my watch, this is an error that propagates. If I could subtract it out, it would just be a constant offset.

Comment: @mike - If you're talking about the +/- 1 second precision associated with trying to read a time off a stopwatch, then that's a "random" error, not a systematic error. An example of a systematic error would be if your stopwatch is running slow or fast.

Comment: And what should I do with the given accuracies  +- 1 s on time and the +- 0.05 m on length?

Comment: @mike - Those are random errors so a least squares fitting program should be able to include those errors when it does its fit. Some of the simpler least squares fitting programs may not take such errors into account and, consequently, will not be able to give you an error on the slope m but simply state the best fit value of m. If you want the errors associated with 'm' and 'c', then use a least squares fitting program that does take into account the error bars associated with the individual data points.